# Saving Inputs to txt. file in Java

Tags: java

I have been building program, where a. teacher is asked for information of 5. students and all the inputs should be saved after to a txt. file. Although my file is always created but is always empty...
Could someone please help me find my mistake ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class programming_project_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {    


        int numbersOfLoops = 1;

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true){
            if (numbersOfLoops == 6){
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("First Name: " );

            String first_name = scn.next();

            System.out.println("Last Name: " );

            String last_name = scn.next();

            System.out.println("Final Score: ");

            int score = scn.nextInt();

            numbersOfLoops++ ;

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("grades.txt");

            System.out.println("First Name: " + first_name);
            System.out.println("Last Name: " + last_name);
            System.out.println("Final Score: " +  score);

            out.close();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never write to `out`. Here:

```
System.out.println("First Name: " + first_name);
System.out.println("Last Name: " + last_name);
System.out.println("Final Score: " +  score);
```

you probably meant `out.println` instead of `System.out.println`.

[`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html) that writes to standard output. `out`, on the other hand, is a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html) you declared and that writes to a file.

Also, you probably want to open the file before the loop and only close it afterwards, otherwise each iteration will overwrite the previous one.

Finally, a couple of asides:

1. that's a weird way of looping 5 times. You could use a `for` instead.
2. You should strive to respect java naming convention. Class names Start with an upper-case letter and use CamelCase, not snake_case. Same for variables, but they start with lower-case letters.

To sum it up:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ProgrammingProject1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {    
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("grades.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.println("First Name: " );
            String firstName = scn.next();

            System.out.println("Last Name: " );
            String lastName = scn.next();

            System.out.println("Final Score: ");
            int score = scn.nextInt();

            out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
            out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
            out.println("Final Score: " +  score);

        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You overmuch for your help! Can you just please tell me why this "out.println("First Name: " + first_name);" should be without "System" at the beginning ?

Comment: @Serdyna because `out` is a variable that will write to the `grades.txt` file, while `System.out` is a variable that will write to the System console.

Comment: @Serdyna I added an explanation about that directly in the answer.